# Formatting timestamp field for output in TemplateToolkit

Tags: perl, postgresql, catalyst, dbix-class, template-toolkit

I'm using Perl with Catalyst framework, DBIx class as ORM, TT for views, Postgresql as DB.

I have a column with 'timestamp without timezone' type, and if I do manual query in Postgres the column value is in such format `2012-08-30 21:30:14`, but when I print the value in TT view file I get it like this `2012-08-30T15:03:13`, so obviously it gets formatted but by what exactly I can't tell.

I want to use [Template::Plugin::Date](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Plugin/Date.pm) to format output timestamps, but I get Catalyst error:

> Couldn't render template "xxx/list.tt2: date error - bad time/date string:  expects 'h:m:s d:m:y'  got: '2012-08-30T21:28:22'"

with code in xxx/list.tt2 `[% date.format(xxx.created) %]`

So how am I supposed to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your timestamp being converted to an object (and then stringified) somewhere between the database and your template?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I can fully understand what is happening to timestamp, but here's some code generated by Catalyst when creating DBIx Schema `xxx.pm`: `__PACKAGE__->load_components("InflateColumn::DateTime", "TimeStamp");` and `__PACKAGE__->add_columns("created",
  { data_type => "timestamp", is_nullable => 0 }, ...`. Other than that in my `list` controller method I just get the whole bunch of `xxx` objects using regular DBIx synthax.

Comment: The `InflateColumn::DateTime` suggests that your timestamp is being converted to a [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/) instance. You could probably call `strftime` on it directly or use the `strftime` method to convert it to a format that the plugin will understand. I haven't done much DBIx, Perl, TT, ... lately so I'm just throwing out some ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You configured DBIx::Class to inflate the value of the 'created' column to a [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) object.

Note that you only need to load the TimeStamp component which is based on InflateColumn::DateTime, not both!

Furthermore you should add `on_connect_call => 'datetime_setup'` to your DBIx::Class `connect_info` to make DBIC set the database datetime format to match what it expects for the DateTime object inflation. This does the right thing for every supported database so it will also work if you switch database or use SQLite for testing.

[Template::Plugin::Date](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aDate) is not for handling DateTime objects, [Template::Plugin::DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aDateTime) is.

Regarding the template rendering I suggest you use [Catalyst::View::TT#expose_methods](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aView%3a%3aTT#expose_methods) feature by adding a method to your Catalyst::View::TT view which gets passed a DateTime object and returns a formatted string. You can add multiple methods for different formats, for example date + time, date only etc.
This way you have a central location which defines the DateTime formatting which can be easily changed if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. A question though regarding "Note that you only need to load the TimeStamp component which is based on InflateColumn::DateTime" - why is that the right way to do things? I followed Catalyst tutorial and there both of the components were loaded.

Comment: Then the Catalyst tutorial is buggy. TimeStamp loads InflateColumn::DateTime: https://metacpan.org/source/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-TimeStamp-0.14/lib/DBIx/Class/TimeStamp.pm#L12

Answer (score 2):

This one should work:

```
[% date.format(xxx.created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) %]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the Date::Format function of Template Tookit, it doesn't work very well. Fortunately your DBIx::Class object can call strftime directly.

To fix your code example:

[% xxx.created.strftime( '%Y-%m-%d %R:%S' )  %]

For other formatting read the strftime manpage.

If you need to repeat the reformatting you might want to use a macro like this:

[% MACRO disp_dt(dt) BLOCK; dt.strftime( '%Y: %B %d' ) ; END %]

[% disp_dt( xxx.created ) %]

Thanks to MST for helping me with this on IRC.

Answer (score -1):

```
date.format(xxx.created.replace('T', ' '));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this one? When I enter this code I get current time in every single column instead of time stored in my DB.

Comment: `$ cat t.tt2`
`[%
    USE date;
    t = '2012-08-30T21:28:22';

    date.format(t.replace('T', ' '));
%]`
`$ tpage t.tt2` 
`21:28:22 30-Aug-2012`