# Setting MySQL time zone at runtime with Perl DBIx

Tags: mysql, perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I have a Perl Catalyst app that store some times in a MySQL database. The times are of type TIMESTAMP and initialized with NOW().

When reading back the times they appear to be in the databases default time zone. However when using the mysql shell I can easily set the time zone by **SET time_zone = '+03:00';** and get the correct local time for my time zone.

Is there a way to set the time one like this in Catalyst or DBIx at run time?

I want to be able to support different time zones, for different users, so just changing the default time zone for the database is not enough. I am also aware that I can format the time in Perl after I get the data from MySQL, but there is so much automation going on with Catalyst, DBIx and Template Toolkit so getting the data correctly from the database to start with would be so much more convenient.

Comment: So, what you want is to retrieve the data and make it so that the DB itself changes the values that you get depending on your parameters. I think this is not a good practice, maybe you should consider storing the timezone along with the times and retrieving both fields, or maybe retrieving a date diff where you actually sum the timezone adjustment to the actuale date.

Comment: I understood that you have datetimes in your DB and you want to present them to the user in the user's local time zone, which is different for each individual user. That's something that should be done in the view. You can make DBIC convert `TIMESTAMP` fields to DateTime objects and work with those. Maybe introduce an automatic filter in your View class that always gets applied to those, and have DateTime handle the conversion.

Comment: Yes, ideally I would like to set the timezone ones and magically have added support for local time zones for my users. If not I guess I will have to add a function in the schema result or view. It is not that that is so hard to do, but it requires multiple changes in a big and complex codebase.

Comment: Note that 'DBIC' is the abbreviation of DBIx::Class, DBIx is the whole DBI eXtenstion namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general advise is to set the datetime in your application, not rely on the datetime of the database server. If you don't need to know which timezone a datetime had when it was set you should store it in UTC. If you need to know the timezone later you need to use a database datatype which supports this like 'timestamp with timezone' in Oracle.

See my answer for [Formatting timestamp field for output in TemplateToolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508641/formatting-timestamp-field-for-output-in-templatetoolkit/14511850#14511850) which seems to be what you're asking.